# Повернуть треугольник относительно отрезка

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика

Пытаюсь нарисовать стрелку (=направленный отрезок=вектор) с механикой как в пэйнте. То есть зажимаем левую клавишу, и, пока не отпустим, рисуется отрезок как в пэйнте, только в конце отрезка (то есть в текущей позиции мыши) должен быть верно направленный треугольник (в моём случае равносторонний). Делаю по шагам: 1) рисую отрезок по 2 точкам; 2) рисую поверх последней точки правильно направленный треугольник. Вопрос по 2 шагу.

Моя библиотека умеет рисовать равносторонний треугольник, а также умеет делать его `rotate(float angle)`, где `angle` - угол **в градусах по часовой стрелке**.

Например, `triangle.rotate(45)` повернет изначальный равносторонний треугольник (симметричный относительно оси `Oy`) на `45` по часовой.

Так вот, проблема в том, чтобы треугольник вращался вместе с "вращающимся" отрезком. На самом деле отрезок не вращается, а каждый раз отрисовывается заново по 2 точкам: там где зажали + текущие координаты мышки. Вот как я получаю угол между моим текущим отрезком и осью `Ox` в `(0;360]`:

```
auto angle = 360.f - std::atan2(second.y - first.y, second.x - first.x) * 180 / 3.14159265f;
if (angle > 360.f)
    angle -= 360;
```

, где `first` - зажатая точка, `second` - текущая. Как от этого угла (а может есть вариант проще) перейти к необходимому для `triangle.rotate(float angle)` углу?

Comment: `angle = 90 - angle;`

Comment: как минимум проще было бы все вычисления проводить в радианах, а не в градусах...

Comment: @Fat-Zer библиотечная функция принимает угол в градусах

Comment: @Igor всё работает!! оказалось проще, чем я думал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как Вы решили отсчитывать угол от оси Y и в направлении, противоположном общепринятому

```
angle = 90 - angle;
```

Comment: А для чего вы убрали код с 360 манипуляциями?

Comment: мне кажется, он там не нужен

Comment: Ну математически мб и не нужен, но учитывая как считает std::atan, у меня не работает без 360. Там угол может быть отрицательный, поэтому я его вот так к положительному приводил. В любом случае, сейчас всё работает, спс